# Need help in configuering derby in eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I am very new to derby and I am really struggling to get correct information. All links led me to see to download derby core plugin fro eclipse which I could not find any more. I just added the jar files in my application and was able to create databases and execute queries. But now I come to the challenging part for me the authentication. I am building a multi user application. I want one administrator with all privileges and users with some privileges. Since my application connects regardless i provide username/password or not I am not able to find a way to make my plans work.
After lot of time spending online I found you can have authorization system level and database level. But I dont have any idea how to do this. Since I just added jar files to my application without doing anything else I am not sure how to make the system level authorization works for me. Here is how i connected..`

```
static Connection connection = null;
static Statement stmnt;


public static void initializeDB (){
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        System.out.println(driver + " loaded.");
    } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void makeConnection(String userName, String password){

    String url = "jdbc:derby:employeeDB";//create=true;" +
                            "user=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";create=true";

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection successful");

        stmnt = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

I have created separate class for dbconection. And I am connecting for the first time. But this user name and password does not make sense as I am not enabling user authentication. I am not sure how to do that. A help would be highly appreciated. And also I would like to have multiple users accessing with different privileges. Please excuse me with my limited knowledge. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. You've clearly made a lot of progress, but you're still trying to learn many different things at once. Regarding user authorization, there is a lot of information in the docs: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/security/csecauthorization.html  You are right that authorization does not make a lot of sense if you are not also doing authentication. Perhaps you can ask a more specific question about what things are giving you trouble.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I really appreciate. I am using derby in eclipse by simply adding jar files into project because I could not find the plugin for eclipse. Is that okey if I am using this way ? I am able to work with databases. But i just want to know how to enable system level authorization. Can you please tell me how to enable that ?

Comment: There is no longer a need for a plugin for Eclipse; those links are old and stale. Just using Eclipse the way you are doing is correct. Regarding authorization, were you able to follow the link in my previous comment?